# How to write hive ql query to combine columns from 2 tables?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables with same schema as

```
table1/table2 comprises of columns item_name and item_qty, sample data looks like
```

**Sample data in table1**

```
item_name    item_qty
item_0001    3
item_0002    7
item_0003    5
item_0004    4
```

**Sample data in table2**

```
item_name    item_qty
item_0003    15
item_0004    2
```

And now I need to combine these 2 tables as described here

```
Sample data in output
item_name    item_qty
item_0001    3
item_0002    7
item_0003    20
item_0004    6
```

How can i write query in hiveQL. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T.item_name,SUM(T.item_qty) AS item_qty
FROM
(
SELECT item_name,item_qty
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT item_name,item_qty
FROM table2
) T
GROUP BY T.item_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on  [How do I join two tables together that are in different databases, in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585302/how-do-i-join-two-tables-together-that-are-in-different-databases-in-hive)

you should do something like this :
SELECT db1.table1.field1, db2.table2.field2
FROM db1.table1 alias1
INNER JOIN db2.table2 alias2 ON alias1.field1 = alias2.field2
INNER JOIN  alias2, db.table3

hope it helps.